# Integrate reports (jasper, Jfreechart) to existing spring mvc project

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, jfreechart

Please, i need to integrate report (Jasper, JfreeChart, or birt) with an existing web Spring mvc project

Comment: wow .. thats really good! go ahead !

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jasper-reports) should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

@user310810, I've written a set of tutorials for integrating Spring MVC 3 and Jasper. I've also provided a downloadable Maven build. The tutorials are very detailed. In addition, the application itself is well-commented. Just leave a comment if the tutorials help you :)

http://krams915.blogspot.com/p/tutorials.html